# Header files in includes are not identified jni c files

Tags: android-ndk, android-ndk-r7

I am very beginner to android native programming. I know this is very basic question, but still i could not solve this. Please support me. 
I have some set of header files residing remotely(not in local_path). But i have included it under includes tree. I am trying to include this header file in a c file present in jni/sample.c Now the problem is that these header files are not recognized. (It shows "unresolved inclusion..etc").  Is this anything related to android.mk file? I did not mention remote header files path anywhere in android.mk file

Answer (score 0):

you have to add the path to these header files to `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` variable you can set inside **Android.mk** (as you rightly guessed):

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += ./path/to/your/includes
```

Comment: @phOb I have NDK in F:/android-ndk-r10\ And my project in F:/android-ndk-r10\samples\AndroidKeyInjector Includes in F:\android-ndk-r10\platforms\android-5\arch-arm\usr\include Then what would be path for includes

Comment: The /usr/include directory of the platform you're compiling against is automatically included, you don't need to add it. If your includes are under AndroidKeyInjector/Includes then you can add `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += ../Includes`

Comment: Thank you. I have edited it, but still header files in jni/sample.c are not recognized. Is this something related to NDK setup? Actually, I imported this project from external source

Comment: This was the project I imported http://www.pocketmagic.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/AndroidKeyInjector.zip

Comment: which header files aren't recognized ?

Comment: Every header file in input.c,uinput.h in jni folder (in above project) are not recognized. I guess it may be because of ndk set setup. Thank you so much for replying

Comment: Could you please tell me whether project mentioned in above link works fine? I am stuck with this since 4 days. I would be grateful to you if you could help me